# Identify the number of active days in an isoweek given a date range

Tags: r

My data are as follows:

```
df <- read_table("begin.date end.date
2019-07-22   2019-07-29
2019-07-29   2019-08-03
2019-08-25   2019-08-30
2019-08-30   2019-09-24
2019-09-30   2019-10-05")
```

I would like to assign two new columns:

isoweek_id = every isoweek in the year (so there will be one row for every week in the year)

data_days = the number of days data collection occurred within that isoweek given the begin.date and end.date, which represent date ranges when data collection occurred.

We might, therefore, have weeks when the number of days data collection occurred is 0 if, for example, a temporal gap in data collection spanned more than one isoweek. (note: my real data have several years worth of data collection).

My desired output would look something like this:

```
begin.date  end.date    isoweek_id  data_days
NA          NA          29          0  
2019-07-22  2019-07-29  30          7 
2019-07-29  2019-08-03  31          6
NA          NA          32          0
NA          NA          33          0
2019-08-25  2019-08-30  34          1
2019-08-25  2019-08-30  35          5 
2019-08-30  2019-09-24  36          7
2019-08-30  2019-09-24  37          7
2019-08-30  2019-09-24  38          7
2019-08-30  2019-09-24  39          2
2019-09-30  2019-10-05  40          6
NA          NA          41          0
NA          NA          42          0
NA          NA          43          0
```

You can look at which isoweeks span which dates as follows:

```
library(ISOweek)
w <- paste("2019-W35", 1:7, sep = "-")
data.frame(weekdate = w, date = ISOweek2date(w))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that every date range larger than one week should be assigned with `7` in `data_days?` And with the same condition, do you want to get the isoweek of `begin.date` or `end.date`? Furthermore, can you please explain, why NA in the date columns can result in a certain isoweek in your desired output?

Comment: @fbeese thank you for your engagement! The below answer has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this does the job:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df %>%  
    dplyr::arrange(begin.date) %>%
    # unnest day sequence from start to end into df https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997084/create-dataframe-of-rows-of-sequence-of-years-from-rows-with-start-end-dates
    dplyr::group_by(rn = dplyr::row_number()) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(dates = list(seq.Date(from = begin.date, to = end.date, by = "days"))) %>% 
    tidyr::unnest(dates) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup() %>%
    # right join list of all dates with iso week and year
    dplyr::right_join(dplyr::tibble(dates = seq.Date(from = min(df$begin.date), max(df$end.date), by = "days")) %>%
                          dplyr::mutate(year = lubridate::year(dates),
                                        iso_week = lubridate::isoweek(dates)),
                      by = "dates") %>%
    # fill up the rn in case it is zero with a number that is larger all rns
    dplyr::mutate(rn = ifelse(is.na(rn), nrow(df) + 1, rn)) %>%
    # summarize data
    dplyr::group_by(year, iso_week, rn) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(bdate =  min(begin.date, na.rm = TRUE), 
                     edate = min(end.date, na.rm = TRUE), 
                     days = sum(ifelse(is.na(begin.date), 0, 1))) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup() %>%
    # get lowest sequential numbering per week since we can have duplicates like the example shows
    dplyr::group_by(year, iso_week) %>%
    dplyr::slice_min(order_by = rn, n = 1) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup() # you might want to remove and or rename comluns

# A tibble: 11 x 6
    year iso_week    rn bdate      edate       days
   <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
 1  2019       30     1 2019-07-22 2019-07-29     7
 2  2019       31     1 2019-07-22 2019-07-29     1
 3  2019       32     6 NA         NA             0
 4  2019       33     6 NA         NA             0
 5  2019       34     3 2019-08-25 2019-08-30     1
 6  2019       35     3 2019-08-25 2019-08-30     5
 7  2019       36     4 2019-08-30 2019-09-24     7
 8  2019       37     4 2019-08-30 2019-09-24     7
 9  2019       38     4 2019-08-30 2019-09-24     7
10  2019       39     4 2019-08-30 2019-09-24     2
11  2019       40     5 2019-09-30 2019-10-05     6
```